# any tutorial on how to add items to listview when scrolling down, showing progress item in the meanwhile?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview whose data is taken from internet.
Data is a list, a long list, so I'd like to display the first, say, 10 results.
If user scrolls down I'd like a progressbar to appear at bottom, while I ask for the next 10 results to server, then remove progressbar and add the new 10 items.

I see this behaviour in the facebook app, can you point me to a tutorial to do something similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, here is a tutorial for a never-ending ListView:
[Android tutorial: Dynamicaly load more items to the ListView ( Never Ending List! )](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-tutorial-dynamicaly)

I've used this in my application and it works flawlessly.

Secondly, this tutorial will teach you how to grab data from the internet and display it in your ListView: [Android Custom ListView with Image and Text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Combine both of them together and you get what you need [Provided you have the basic knowledge of Android programming. Goodluck ;)]